# Google calendar API notification for reminder

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm creating a web app in which every user could have multiple calendars.
What I'm looking for is when the user creates a new Event and set up reminders I want when reminder occurs to get a push notification on the server side.

Google calendar API provides push notification on Event change but I can't find how to achieve my use case.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Maybe you can get some more info reading the full dev pages. https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: Thats not how reminders work, reminders send notification to the User.  Not to the application that create the event.

Comment: Sure it doesn't work that way. My initial purpose was to delegate the event management to google calendar. Then my app receive a notification and I create a push notidication to the user